# Leaflet.minichart using R in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, leaflet.draw, r-leaflet

### Background

I'm no familiar with Javascript language, then I have tried the package **leaflet.minicart** using R inside the Jupyter notebook.

Writting the example code as follows:

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```

However, the output cell can not be well represented. Maybe the figure below is not very clear, the output map is fixed to a narrow strip.

[image]

Meanwhile, I opened the saved html file (uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=154QXqnNI_IPsPnkEoOjThT7DRq4QlZa_)) in browser, the background map was not able to be shown.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? The proposed one is based on RStudio but not Jupyter. I am having the same issue than you (using your code example)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your first problem, the map displays fine in my RStudio Viewer. For the grey html background it was answered here:

[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187926/leaflet-output-is-grey][1]

use:

```
library(leaflet);library(htmlwidgets)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")%>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) 
saveWidget(m, file="m.html")
```

Comment: I think the question is about the problem in visualization in Jupyter not in RStudio. Getting the same problem myself. The map can be seen but the output cell in Jupyter is very narrow

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/04/r-htmlwidgets-in-jupyter-notebooks/

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(IRdisplay)
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")

saveWidget(m, 'demo.html', selfcontained = TRUE)
display_html('<iframe src="demo.html"></iframe>')
```

[image]